# Creating an embed with buttons acting as a menu

Tags: discord.js, discord-buttons

So, im new at this, and I'm trying to create a command that has buttons, and when you press a button the embed changes. Im currently using discord.js v14, but I don't know if it's recommended to use v13.

The problem that I'm getting is that when I click a button of the embed, it loads and then says "Interaction failed", while not showing anything in the console. Any help?

Command code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('testeando')
    .setDescription('test'),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const message = await interaction.deferReply({
            fetchReply: true
        });
        
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Test embed')
            .setDescription('Hola que ondaaaa');

        const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Seeee')
            .setDescription('Hola que ondaaaa');

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setLabel('Boton 1')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
                    .setCustomId('button1'),
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setLabel('Boton 2')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                    .setCustomId('button2'),
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setLabel('Boton 3')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
                    .setCustomId('button3'),
            )

            
        await interaction.editReply({
            embeds: [embed], components: [row]
        });
        
        const filter = i => i.customId === 'button1' || i.customId === 'button2';
        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });
        
        collector.on('collect', async i => {
            await i.deferUpdate();
    
            if (i.customId === 'button1') {
                await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] });
            } else if (i.customId === 'button2') {
                await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed2], components: [row] });
            }

            collector.on('end', async () => {
                await interaction.editReply({ components: [] });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Already tried doing `createMessageComponentCollector()` but it seems to be replaced in v14.

Answer (score 1):

The "interactionFailed" error comes from the interaction not being acknowledged. Your code looks similar to a reaction collector works- which isn't how the button interaction works in Discord.

To acknowledge a button, you can treat it similar to the way you treat an application command (Slash Command).

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    // determine if this is a button
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

    // get the button's ID
    const buttonPress = client.buttons.get(interaction.customId);

    // run the code- this can be done however you want- I chose to do it this way.
    await buttonPress.execute(interaction);
});
```

Once you have the event properly acknowledged, you can use the get the message that the button is attached to by using `interaction.message` and then `interaction.message.edit()` to edit the embed (or anything about the original message, as long as the bot sent it).